# Spring-Integration: Cannot Consume from custom message adapter using IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have created a MessageAdapter by extending MessageProducerSupport. I produce message to output channel by calling `MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage`. Then I defined an IntegrationFlow to consume messages from the message adapter, and send it to a channel. But I don't receive any messages on the channel.

This is my configuration

```
 @Bean
  public MyAdapter myAdapter() {
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
    myAdapter.setOutputChannel(new QueueChannel());
    return myAdapter;
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(myAdapter())
        .channel("myChannel")
        .get();
  }
```

and message endpoint for "myChannel":

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MyConsumer {

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myChannel")
  public void parseMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println(message.getPayload().toString());
  }

}
```

Is there something I am missing to configure?

Thank you

Comment: What triggers the `sendMessage`? Turn on DEBUG logging to see if it helps.

Comment: @GaryRussell My adapter gets messages from KCL record processor and triggers the sendMessage on `MessageProducerSupport`. I changed the above code and added a `PollableChannel` bean and passed it to output channel. Debug shows `preSend` and `postSend` successfully done on that output channel.

Comment: So, do you mean that messages are sent to that `new QueueChannel()`, but not to the `"myChannel"` in the flow? Try remove the `@Bean` annotation from the `myAdapter()` definition - the Java DSL will take care about bean registration for you.

Comment: That's right! I debugged the code and I can verify messages are hold by the channel (`new QueueChannel()`) in `GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(...)`, but it seems they are not polled. I also removed `@Bean` from `myAdapter()`, did not help.

Comment: @ArtemBilan @GaryRussel I just removed `new QueueChannel()` and output channel is set to default `DirectChannel()` by `IntegrationFlow`. Now it works fine. I don't understand why manual setting outputchannel does not work!

Comment: It works, but it sends a message to the provided `new QueueChannel()`, not that one you configure in the flow.

Comment: Right! then how can I poll messages from `new QueueChannel()` ?